# Ubuntu / Windows 7 Dual Boot, Can't update Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, updates, multi-boot

So I installed Ubuntu (9.04, I believe) on my Windows 7 partition, booted into Ubuntu and I can't update any software:

"Could not download all repository indexes"

... and then a list of "Fail to fetch ..."

I can't connect to the internet, but obviously there's something else going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 9.04 is older than 18 months, and is not a "long term support" release, so updates for it are no longer available.

You'll have to upgrade to 9.10, 10.04, 10.10, 11.04, 11.10 (or stop at 10.04 if you want an LTS release)

You can find out more on how to upgrade an end-of-life Ubuntu version on [EOLUpgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades) on the Ubuntu Wiki.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't think that the updates would stop being supported so soon.

Comment: 18 months for "regular" releases, 5 years (3 on desktop) for "long term" releases. The upcoming 12.04 will get 5 years of support on both desktop and server.